# Enforce initializing superclass's ivar after calling superclass's init method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to enforce the initialization of an ivar in a superclass but that ivar usually can not be initialized without other data in the subclass to be initialized.  The two solutions I have thought of is:

1. pass the required generated key for the ivar to the superclass's init method
2. calling a second superclass method from the subclass's init method

Here is example (contrived, non-working) code.  The stringBasedOnSubclassKey ivar should be initialized to the NSString from the subclass's key method.

```
@interface MySuperclass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *stringBasedOnSubclassKey;
@end

@interface MySubclass : MySuperclass
    @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) int value;
@end

@implementation MySubclass

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _value = 30;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)key
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UniqueKey-%d", self.value];
}
```

So the question is is there a way to enforce the initialization of the stringBasedOnSubclassKey ivar using the return value of the "key" method?  I don't believe I can enforce solution 1 and 2 above.  These subclasses may also be created by other outside developers so the key method may be more complicated than this.

Update: I am dealing with existing subclasses of this base class so solutions limiting the changes to existing subclasses is a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the getter for `stringBasedOnSubclassKey` in such a way as to force initialization of it:

```
- (NSString *) stringBasedOnSubclassKey {
    if !(_stringBasedOnSubclassKey) {
        _stringBasedOnSubclassKey = // whatever;
    }
    return _stringBasedOnSubclassKey;
}
```

And write the superclass `key` method to throw an exception, thus forcing the client to override it in the subclass.

Comment: This is a good solution but I was hoping to perform the initialization when the object is initialized to avoid the if statement.  It will be called thousands of times by somewhat time critical code.  I will profile to see if it really makes that much difference to use the if statement on 5000 calls.

Comment: A single nil check takes no time at all. - However, my answer was based on a misunderstanding of your question; I thought the point was that you couldn't know the key until after init was over. If you *can* do it in init, then of course do it in init, in accordance with the other answer.

Comment: Your understanding was correct, as I can not guarantee the subclass has fully initialized the key until after it has completed it's initialization.  The only way I can think of to do it in the init is to call a superclass method to perform the initialization at the end of the subclasses init method.  But I have no way to enforce other developers forgetting to call that method in their own subclass.  So your solution is the safest and doesn't require existing subclasses to change.

Comment: "as I can not guarantee the subclass has fully initialized the key until after it has completed it's initialization" - That was exactly my thought.